# How do i write the following years?

Tags: numbers

How are these numbers

> 1052, 1053, 1052, 1058, 1552, 1552, 1870 and 1880

pronounced / written in the context of a year of a particular date in german?

Comment: What does your dictionary say about pronounciation of german numbers? Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: I am asking about years, as if i remember correctly Germans pronounce their years differently from their numbers.

Comment: No, they don't. Unless you mean something like _"achtzehnhundertziebzig"_, that's just much like zulu time (military) in english (only applies for numbers bigger than 1100.)

Comment: At least I believe this is a useful question, because it is really a bit of an exception, how numbers are usually pronounced or written. I hope you are OK with my clarifying edits (that this is your homework isn't relevant in the context).

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean the exception, when it is usual to say "**Fünfzehnhundert**zweiundfünfzig" for *1552*, instead of *"Eintausendfünfhundertzweiundfünfzig"* when used in the context of a particular dates year.

That's kind of a short form for *"Im Jahr(e) Eintausendfünfhundertzweiundfünfzig"* and comes from the common use to measure historical timespans in centuries.

The build rules are very similar as for the english [*military time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) where zero minutes are spelled out as *hundred* (e.g. *(zero)ninehundred* for 9:00AM, *elevenhundred* for 11:00AM or *eighteenhundred* for 6:00PM), but *1000 - 1099* make an exception. We say e.g. *"Tausenddreiundfünfzig"*, *"Tausendachtundziebzig"* in that context.

Thus your date year numbers would be pronounced / written as

- 1052 => *Tausendzweiundfünfzig*
- 1053 => *Tausenddreiundfünfzig*
- 1058 => *Tausendachtundfünfzig*
- 1552 => *Fünfzehnhundertzweiundfünfzig*
- 1870 => *Achtzehnhundertsiebzig*
- 1880 => *Achtzehnhundertachtzig*

Comment: Did you mean:  "1000–1099"? And what about "Wilhelm ging Zehnsechsundsechzig über den Kanal"?